# Open an app when another app is clicked

Tags: ios

Is there any way on iOS to detect a click on an app icon, or know that an app is currently being used, and open a separate different app? Say I click on Notes and then it redirects and opens Evernote. Basically any arbitrary app is clicked and another app is opened instead. I was thinking it may have something to do with URL schemes. Im really new to iOS dev so forgive me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

No. That would be really counterproductive and a security risk for users (it's pretty much the equivalent of phishing). If you come from Android maybe you are referring to default apps, but iOS doesn't allow third party default apps for now.

You can detect if a specific app is installed using `canOpenURL(_:)`. See the official docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622952-canopenurl).

Comment: Not really default apps, rather the ability of an app to detect an app click and either give a notification or open itself instead. Im assuming thats still not possible

Comment: Detect an app "click" inside another app ? That'd constitute a huge privacy leak. You can open an app from another app, or send data to another app but it's not the same as the use case you are describing.